# issue in logging into salesforce org

Tags: logging

I am facing issues frequently while logging into the salesforce Developer org. I have attached the screen shot of the issues below.

[image]

[image]

Also even when I enter the correct username and password, it often shows invalid username and password.

Please help me to sort out

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you contacted support?

Comment: or cleared your cache or tried a different browser?